# I have one query in android coding about button linking

Tags: java, android, xml, facebook

I am new to the android and I have to link four buttons to different social sites like facebook twitter youtube and instagram also shown below in the image [image]

I have already created  buttons and I am linking all buttons to different xml files but I want to ask you friends that for linking xml files I am creating different activity like 
socialactivityf.java for facebook
socialactivityt.java for twitter
socialactivityy.java for youtube etc.

so I am thinking to create one socialactivity.java and link all the four button to different xml files is it possible

If possible I have written the code for facebook and can I edit this code and send it to twitter from this file itself

I have to add for twitter,youtube  in the same file or should I compulsory add another file.

Comment: pls can anyone write the code beow

Comment: Why different xml files for each buttons ?

Comment: i dont know how to code i am new to android so can u code it and give it to me pls @GrIsHu

Comment: No actualy i have done an webview in diffrent xml files so asking there it will show the facebook page@GrIsHu

Comment: show your layout code.